# Casting in Haskell

Tags: haskell, visualhaskell

a) I need to cast from `String` to `int` in haskell. I have a function that gets the third word in a sentence as a string, but my third word in all my sentences are numbers (int), how can I cast from string to int so then I can use the number afterwards to do operations like add or mult?

```
getThirdWord :: String -> String
getThirdWord = head . tail . tail . words
```

b) I'm using Visual Haskell Studio. How can I use functions like `map` and `zip` in visual haskell studio? Are there any plugins that I need to include to my vhs to make them work?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 14):

[Yacoby's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803750/casting-in-haskell/1803763#1803763) is correct of course. Let me make two remarks:

1. [`read`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3Aread) is very general. It not only converts `String` to `Int`. Its return type depends on the context. In this case `getThirdWord` is defined to be `String -> Int`, so `read` knows what to do. This is not always the case, so if you ever get a compile error while using `read`, remember this: you may need to help Haskell figure out the return type.
2. Currently you use `head . tail . tail` to get the third list element. What if you wanted, say, the 23rd element? A more maintainable and readable solution is to use [`(!!)`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3A!!): this way you can retrieve a list element at any index. Thus:

   ```
   thirdWordAsInt :: String -> Int 
   thirdWordAsInt = read . (!! 2) . words
   ```

   (Note the 2 instead of a 3, since indices are 0-indexed.)

Answer (score 6):

Regarding casting, take a look at the [read](http://www.zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/read_f.html) function.

```
getThirdWord :: String -> Int
getThirdWord = read . head . tail . tail . words
```

[Visual Haskell Studio](http://www.haskell.org/visualhaskell/) seems to be an [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) only, in that the backend uses [GHC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasgow_Haskell_Compiler), which fully supports the Haskell specification and includes the libraries that include map and fold.

Answer (score 3):

I second Yacoby to use `read`, but keep in mind that both `head`/`tail` and `read` are partial functions and may fail on empty list. I think it's better to avoid `head` if you can use pattern matching instead. For example,

```
get3rd :: String -> String
get3rd s =
  case (take 3 $ words s) of
    [_,_,w]   -> w
    otherwise -> ""
```

This function is safe for any input (it just returns an empty string if there are less than 3 words). Certainly, if you are absolutely sure the lists are always non-empty, you can use `head`/`tail`.

With `read` you can either catch exceptions (not very convenient), or use `reads` instead:

```
toInt :: String -> Maybe Int
toInt s =
  case reads s of
    [(i,_)]   -> Just i
    otherwise -> Nothing

-- test cases
main = do
  print . toInt . get3rd $ "1 2 3"
  print . toInt . get3rd $ "one two three"
  print . toInt . get3rd $ "short list"
```

This `toInt` returns `Just` a number or `Nothing` if it cannot parse. Alternatively you can use [Safe library](http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/safe/) and its `readMay` function.

Comment: You should add that it's perfectly fine to use `last` and `head` as long as you know for sure that you wont be dealing with an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

You guys are all right, but I post because I think there is a very elegant and useful function I came up with when learning to help with the *read*ing and *show*ing of text.

```
as :: (Read a, Show a) => (a -> a) -> String -> String
as f = show . f . read

Prelude> as (+1) "7"
"8"

Prelude> as (+(1/2)) "5"
"5.5"
```

Useful, eh?  =P.  Also *xs !! n* gets xs's n'th element.  Look at others answers for easy ways to print.

Comment: Why not `(Read a, Show b) => (a -> b) -> String -> String` as the type?

Comment: Touche.  Yours makes sense, I guess I just did this for simplicity.